# Url structure for profile in laravel using routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am having a sentry laravel 4 setup.

at this moment for profile view I should be going to link like this

```
http://localhost/ffdd/public/3/show
```

where 3 is user id

and I am using following route

```
Route::get('/{profile}/show', array('as' => 'profile.show', 'uses' => 'ProfilesController@show'));
```

I need the same result for the link

```
http://localhost/ffdd/public/3
```

what should I change in route.

and for future I want this user id place to username .

Edit 2

my current route structure is like this.

```
Route::get('/{userId?}', array('as' => 'profile', 'uses' => 'ProfilesController@index')); 
Route::post('/{userId?}', array('as' => 'profile-koko', 'uses' => 'Controllers\Account\ProfileController@postIndex'));

Route::get('/{profile}/show', array('as' => 'profile.show', 'uses' => 'ProfilesController@show'));
```

when the index of profilescontroller receive a route request it just forward it to show method.

```
 // User is logged in
                $user = Sentry::getUser();
                $user = $user->id;

                //return View::make('profiles.index');
                return Redirect::action('ProfilesController@show', array('userId'=>$user));
            }
```

when I am using this

```
Route::get('{profile}',array(
        'as'    =>  'test2',
        'uses'  =>  'ProfilesController@show',
    ));
```

as my friend itachi said in his reply !

I am getting this error !

```
Some mandatory parameters are missing ("profile") to generate a URL for route "profile.show".
```

**edit 3**

```
<?php

# Profile

Route::get('/{userId?}', array('as' => 'profile', 'uses' => 'ProfilesController@index')); 
Route::post('/{userId?}', array('as' => 'profile-koko', 'uses' => 'Controllers\Account\ProfileController@postIndex'));

Route::resource('profile', 'ProfilesController@show');


Route::get('{profile}/show',array(
        'as'    =>  'profile.show',
        'uses'  =>  'ProfilesController@show',
    ));

    Route::get('{profile}',array(
        'as'    =>  'test2',
        'uses'  =>  'ProfilesController@show',
    ));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't see any use of defining two routes for the same action. but still, if you want it, here it goes.

just create two routes pointing to the same action. e.g.

```
    Route::get('{profile}/show',array(
        'as'    =>  'test1',
        'uses'  =>  'ProfileController@show',
    ));

    Route::get('{profile}',array(
        'as'    =>  'test2',
        'uses'  =>  'ProfileController@show',
    ));
```

now, you can access both the routes `http://localhost/ffdd/public/3/show` and `http://localhost/ffdd/public/3`

but there is a problem here. `{profile}` parameter can match anything.

e.g.

*http://localhost/ffdd/public/3/show* [will call the ProfileController@show as intended]

*http://localhost/ffdd/public/asdf/show* [will also call the ProfileController@show **which was NOT INTENDED!**]

to avoid this issue, you have two ways.

1. Declare these two routes at the very end of the file so that other routes get precedence.
2. As `{profile}` must be an id [for now], let's put a constraint to it by declaring the follwoing,

`Route::pattern('profile', '[0-9]+');`

Now, the `{profile}` will match only for numerics.

**So the whole code becomes**

```
    Route::pattern('profile', '[0-9]+');

    Route::get('{profile}/show',array(
        'as'    =>  'test1',
        'uses'  =>  'ProfileController@show',
    ));

    Route::get('{profile}',array(
        'as'    =>  'test2',
        'uses'  =>  'ProfileController@show',
    ));
```

there wont be any conflicts here as `{profile}` must be a numeric to evoke the `ProfileController@show` action.

**Alternative way to put constraint**:

There is also an alternative way to put constraint using `where`.

e.g.

```
Route::get('{profile}/show',array(
    'as'    =>  'test1',
    'uses'  =>  'ProfileController@show',
))->where('profile', '[0-9]+');
```

but if you go this way, you need to put this `where` in every routes that you use `{profile}`.

Comment: itachi, I have little edited that question. Thanks for reply. I am the same person who was getting ur help at chat last night ! thanks man.

Comment: you have too much routes without a pattern. you are using `Route::resources` along with route mapping which makes very hard to track as what route is being used. Remove all the routes and add one by one. else, it is almost impossible to spot what is going wrong.

Comment: I am using this route structure only (removing all others)

pls see edit 3 

and it is giving the same error 

`Symfony \ Component \ Routing \ Exception \ MissingMandatoryParametersException
Some mandatory parameters are missing ("profile") to generate a URL for route "profile.show".`

Comment: it is solved brother ! the only error was , Route::get('/{userId?}', array('as' => 'profile-okok', 'uses' => 'ProfilesController@index'));

should be

ProfilesController@show

Comment: I need no two route now as I never want /show in the link.
But I want to improve the user id in the link to username , if you can help me it will be awesome ! thanks bro :)